# Use new UINavigationBarAppearance() API to set navigationBar color on a single ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uikit

I need to setUp a NavigationBar color for a single `ViewController`. What Im currently doing is setting up the nav color on `viewDidLoad()` and resetting it to .clear (so it uses whatever color is set on the newly pushed VC) on `viewWillDissappear`. While this sorta works, it is not fast enough as the .clear color is not applied until the pushing animation is over, resulting in like half a second of the navigationBar color being visible until it is finally resetted to .clear.

Current code looks like this:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        navigationController?.navigationBar.setNavBarColor(color: .red)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        navigationController?.navigationBar.setNavBarColor(color: .clear)
}


func setNavBarColor(color: UIColor) {
    let appearance: UINavigationBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    appearance.configureWithTransparentBackground()
    appearance.backgroundColor = color
    self.standardAppearance = appearance
    self.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
}
```

This works but isnt fast enough as the changes take effect only after the pushing animation ends. Any tip?

Answer (score 0):

Set your navigation bar with my extension:

```
extension UIViewController {
func configureNavigationBar(largeTitleColor: UIColor, backgoundColor: UIColor, tintColor: UIColor, title: String, preferredLargeTitle: Bool) {
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
navBarAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
navBarAppearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: largeTitleColor]
navBarAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: largeTitleColor]
navBarAppearance.backgroundColor = backgoundColor
navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = navBarAppearance
navigationController?.navigationBar.compactAppearance = navBarAppearance
navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = navBarAppearance

navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = preferredLargeTitle
navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = tintColor
navigationItem.title = title

} else {
// Fallback on earlier versions
navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = backgoundColor
navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = tintColor
navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
navigationItem.title = title
  }
 }
}
```

call it in viewWillAppear or viewDidLoad and change your background colors, in your case set background to clear... How to use:

```
configureNavigationBar(largeTitleColor: .black, backgoundColor: .white, tintColor: .black, title: "yourTitle", preferredLargeTitle: true)
```

In your case, call configureNavigationBar func in viewWillAppear of start controller, call configureNavigationBar in viewDidLoad of destination controller.. ES:
In SceneDelegate set your start controller under scene function:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    let controller = UINavigationController(rootViewController: StartController())
    window?.rootViewController = controller
    if #available(iOS 13, *) {
        window?.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark
    }
}
```

this is StartController:

```
import UIKit

class StartController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "GO", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleGo))
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    configureNavigationBar(largeTitleColor: .white, backgoundColor: .black, tintColor: .white, title: "Start", preferredLargeTitle: true)
}

@objc fileprivate func handleGo() {
    let controller = DestinationController()
    navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
 }
}
```

This is DestinationController:

```
import UIKit

class DestinationController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    configureNavigationBar(largeTitleColor: .white, backgoundColor: .red, tintColor: .white, title: "Destination", preferredLargeTitle: true)
 }
}
```

the result:

[image]

Comment: Doesnt seem to be working when setting .clear as navBar color on the destination VC. Try doing view.backgroundColor = .purple to force your destination VC to be entirely purple, then setting a clear navBar color on viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear and check results. Im getting the same delay in changing navBar colors when pushing from one VC to the other.